# My background is cutting off for mobile browsers (along with iPad)

Tags: html, css

My website is not showing up properly on mobile devices. The background ends on the right and I need to add padding to the site in general.

Link to site : http://www.surrealpixel.com/cp -- I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>
```

change your view port meta tag with this, if it is not working you can use initial scale like this if this is not working

and there is a difference between body and wrapper widths. Body :1024, Wrapper:1200

Answer (score 0):

This behavior doesn't only affect mobile devices, it has something to do with small screen sizes in general and can be reproduced on your desktop machine as well. For instance, check out what happens on your desktop machine once you zoom into this site by pressing `CTRL +` a few times.

This is a somewhat silly behavior of `width: 100%`. I typically fix this by adding a `min-width`.
In your case, try `min-width: 1200px` instead of `min-width: 1024px` in your `style.css`.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your CSS (preferably in top)

```
html, body {
    width: 1200px;
}
```